# <img src> tag issue while practicing Html on macbook

Tags: html

Can someone please give me a clear idea on why image does not show up when I use the `<img src>` tag as `<img src="../../newimg.jpg">` but Image gets displayed when I use `<img src="../../newimg.jpg ">`. Got the difference? Image gets displayed only when I give a space between **newimg.jpg** and '**"**'. Don't know why this happens.

I'm using macbook pro.
Tried the same code in textedit and BBedit.

Code and image are under same folder.

/Documents/website/index.html.

/Documents/website/newimg.jpg

**Update**

When I manually checked the image file name I was unable to identify any spaces after .jpg but when I inspect the image I think I found something.
[image: **Test 1**]

[image: **Test 2**]

Comment: Please add your html

Comment: It's entirely possible that you have a space character in your filename without realising it.

Comment: checkout the image file name again.

Comment: To the people down voting. At least come up with a explanation and a solution for my doubt. I'm no genius like you guys after all.

Comment: To the people who wants to close this question. There are lot of guys out there who are dumb as me. I think I've spent 5+ hours trying to resolve this issue and in these 5 hours, I found no solution addressing this issue in the web including stackoverflow so please let this question be. it might help few guys like me.

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out. You have curly quotes (“ ”) in your img tag. Change those to the standard type of quotes. (" ")

Comment: I do not know how the curly quotes came in. I just modified it now, it works good. Thanks for your help and effort.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's actually possible to make a space after the extension on a Mac. Are you sure the file doesn't have a space after the ".jpg" in its name?

Edit: Try saving the image with a new name, and make sure there isn't a space after the ".jpg"

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Let me inspect and update my question.

Comment: See another suggestion above. I haven't used a Mac in a while, but I'm trying my best to offer suggestions.

Comment: Tried manually and when I did there was no space after .jpg. It's only showing in the inspector. Tried using different set of images too.